# How to put data from s3 to se glacier in new s3 UI, can I keep data in both s3 and s3-glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a folder in a bucket and I want to particularly send that data to s3 glacier , how can I send that particular folder to s3 glacier and still keep it in my s3 bucket. Please guide. I have tried but its hard to figure out

Comment: Having data both in regular S3 and glacier does not really make sense. What are you planning on doing with the data?

Comment: @luk2302         I have few things which still access data from that s3 location so I can't put my data from s3 to s3 glacier and completely forget it. Is it not possible ? Also I would know how to put data from s3 to s3 glacier . I created a life cycle rule and gave number of days to delete the object from s3 is 0 , will that work or I have to provide minimum number of days 1 ?

Comment: You move data to glacier if you have infrequent access and want to save on storage pricing, keeping the data in regular storage just adds the pricing of glacier on top without any benefit. It only makes sense to move data, not copy it. And if you have frequent accesses glacier is wrong in general. Just use intelligent tiering.

Comment: @luk2302, I get your point but I want to know first how can I put data instantly from s3 to glacier , Can you guide with that?

Comment: @luk2302, I have done the transfer but how long will it take to move or copy , Days to retention I have put is 0 but the data doesn't seem to go from s3 and is still there

Comment: S3 lifecycle rules are generally processed once a day, and in some cases it can take more than 24 hours for a rule to be processed.  In other words, wait at least 24 hours to see the transition occur.

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks a lot , do we have bash script where I Can directly upload data to s3 vault(glacier ) from my local machine(computer) Please let me know

Comment: I have no clue what bash scripts you have.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of "Glacier" on AWS:

- **The original Amazon Glacier** is a service that uses terminology like Vault and Archive. It is slow, painful to use and is actually more expensive. It should be avoided these days.
- There are also **Glacier Storage Classes available in Amazon S3** that can move objects into 'Glacier' while still being visible in Amazon S3. These offerings are **cheaper and easier to use**.

Objects in Amazon S3 can be moved to the **Glacier storage classes** via:

- The **Amazon S3 management console** (Actions / Edit storage class)
- [Transitioning objects using Amazon S3 Lifecycle - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html)
- Programmatically by calling an AWS SDK

The **objects will still 'appear' to be in Amazon S3**, but their content will not be immediately accessible. You will need to **Restore** the object to have access to its content. Think of it like an entry in a **library catalog**, but having to retrieve the book from a shelf before you can read it.